# How to Dynamically Added Stored Procedure Programmatically Using C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I successfully added my database table using c# programmatically, but in my stored procedure it trigger error while executing, a through exception is `{"Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'GO'.\r\n'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'go'."}`
I don’t know why, can anyone help me !

**SQL query** --which is working

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_checkIfExistTempIndividualRoomUpdateAPI]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @string varchar(150)  -- url

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select id from individual_room_update_api_temp_table 
    where url =@string
END
go
```

***I changed the SQL query to C#***

```
string sp = "GO\n"
           + "SET ANSI_NULLS ON\n"
           + "GO\n"
           + "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON\n"
           + "GO\n"
           + "\n"
           + "create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_checkIfExistTempIndividualRoomUpdateAPI]\n"
           + "  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here\n"
           + "  @string varchar(150)  -- url\n"
           + "\n"
           + "AS\n"
           + "BEGIN\n"
           + "  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from\n"
           + "  -- interfering with SELECT statements.\n"
           + "  SET NOCOUNT ON;\n"
           + "\n"
           + "    -- Insert statements for procedure here\n"
           + "  select id from individual_room_update_api_temp_table \n"
           + "  where url =@string\n"
           + "END\n"
           + "go";

 string Connection = "Data Source= " + cbServer.Text +"; Initial Catalog= HMS; Integrated Security = true; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;";
MainClass.ExecuteQuery(sp, Connection);
```

In My **Main Class**

```
 public static bool ExecuteQuery(string query, string con)
{
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con) )
     {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
       {
         connection.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
         return true;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Remove the first go.  Error indicates there is nothing to execute before the first go.

Comment: Why not convert your query to Stored Procedure in MSSQL and call it ?
You can also create a dynamic query and pass the contents of the dynamic part to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: [GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) is not Transact-SQL statements, there for it is not valid syntax.  You can use [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) instead if your source contains `GO`

Comment: @Squirrel ok thanks, let me try it

Comment: I am not saying the current method does not work at all. It just will not handle GO. SMO which is a SSMS object does that

Comment: Consider using multiline verbatim strings `@""` to make it more readable

Answer (score -1):

1. Please create a resx file (Resource file) and store the SP there.
   You don't need make .NET code dirty. Create a Resource File Queries.resx. For Key => **MySqlQuery**,
   For Value =>

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_checkIfExistTempIndividualRoomUpdateAPI]

@URL_PARAM varchar(150)

AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   select id from individual_room_update_api_temp_table 
   where url =@URL_PARAM
   END
go
```

2. Now the .net part,

```
public static bool ExecuteQuery(string query, string con, string paramValue)
{
     query = Queries.MySqlQuery;
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con) )
     {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
       {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@URL_PARAM", paramValue);
         connection.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
         return true;
        }
     }
}
```

Looks like data is not bound in the query as well.

Comment: while I added ```cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;``` it trigger ```The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect```, can you please show me in code?

Comment: `GO` is not a TSQL command so this won't work. It's a batch separator, you split the batches at `GO`